# A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. Angular Datatable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following `DataTable DataSource` code which does not compile. I am getting the following compilation error.

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

```
  connect(): Observable<Product[]> {
    this.productsService.getProducts();
    this.productsService
      .getProductUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
        this.products = products;
      });
  }
```

My service class has the following code.

```
  getProducts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; products: Product[] }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/products'
      )
      .subscribe(productData => {
        this.products = productData.products;
        this.productsUpdated.next([...this.products]);
      });
  }

  getProductUpdateListener() {
    return this.productsUpdated.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Which Datatable Library are you using? Please add a link to that and some sample JSON Data to work with. Adding a [REPREX](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) using a Sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) would be great as well.

Comment: The error itself is sufficiently-descriptive that you should be able to understand the problem with your code. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it. I removed the connect() function and moved it to ngOnit. And made slight modifications.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getProducts();
    this.productsService
      .getProductUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
        this.products = products;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.products);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`return`** to the method **`connect`**, or just add a keyword void if you do not want to return anything from the method

```
connect(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return  this.productsService.getProducts();
  return   this.productsService.getProductUpdateListener()
```

Comment: by default the connect() method expects me return an observable. I did try to add the return statement, it did not work.

Comment: when i tried to add the return statement - `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'`

Comment: just change it to connect():void {} and see if you are getting expected result

Comment: `connect()` is the default method for angular datatable, it will not allow void.

Comment: try adding return keyword to your service method as well